# How do you set the maxreceivedmessagesize wcf setting in code on a wcf service with no config file that is hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, configuration, settings, maxreceivedmessagesize

I have inherited a project that contains a set of wcf services that is hosted in iis with no config file entries.  I need to increase the maxreceivedmessagesize wcf setting.  How would I do this in code?

Comment: If you're on .NET 4.0 or later, you could also set a default binding in the config file with the larger size for `maxReceivedMessageSize`.  Then you wouldn't need to do anything in the code (unless you want to).

Answer (score 2):

Try with this piece of code,

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = proxy.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

**For future reference**, you can add this in your web.config (as @Tim suggested in the comments). Note that the basicHttpBinding doesn't have a name specified, so it becomes the default config for that binding type.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```